# prolog to SQL converter

Tags: sql, prolog, transpiler

Without thinking to much, it seems to me that a large set of Prolog's functionality could be implemented as relational calculus (a.k.a. SQL).

Has anyone heard of any tools to automatically convert Prolog to SQL?

Comment: No, I don't know of any, but feel free to give it a shot :-)

Comment: Wow. There sure is potential for discovery, still, in this world! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recommending:

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/prolog/code/io/pl2sql/0.html

my advice- use Eclipse prolog (http://www.eclipseclp.org/) (not (here) to be confused with prolog in the eclipse IDE).

I spent hours trying to get the code to compile in 4 other prologs(!) and 4 minutes to compile in eclipse.

When it works, it's a thing of beauty.

Credit to Herr Draxler of course

Answer (score 35):

Yes, of course.

A premise for skeptics: any semi-decent book on database theory mentions [Datalog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog) (which is Prolog-like) and theorems which demonstrate that is possible to translate it to/from Relational Algebra (RA) (under specific restrictions).

SQL is not faithful to RA or relational calculi, but is enough to support Prolog:

- [Christoph Draxler](http://www.phonetik.uni-muenchen.de/institut/mitarbeiter/draxler/draxler.html) has developed a Prolog to SQL compiler (PL2SQL) for his thesis, [available for download](http://www.phonetik.uni-muenchen.de/institut/mitarbeiter/draxler/prolog_sql.tgz) (.tgz) - also here at [CMU Artificial Intelligence Repository](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/ai-repository/ai/lang/prolog/code/io/pl2sql/0.html) (it was adapted and included in at least: [Ciao Prolog](http://clip.dia.fi.upm.es/Software/Ciao/ciao_html/ciao_152.html) and [SWI-Prolog](http://www.berkeleybop.org/blipdoc/doc/users/cjm/cvs/blipkit/packages/blip/sql/sql_compiler.pro) via [Blipkit - Biomedical LogIc Programming Knowledge Integration Kit](http://www.blipkit.org/));
- Igor Wojnicki has developed for his PhD ([A Rule-based Inference Engine Extending Knowledge Processing Capabilities of Relational Database Management Systems](http://home.agh.edu.pl/~wojnicki/phd/)) a prototype system implementing his [Jelly View technology](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1066822) called **ReDaReS**, but it seems not available for download;
- [Relational Abstract Machine (RAM)](http://babel.ls.fi.upm.es/research/ram/) translates Prolog to Relational Algebra, but it doesn't seems to have a SQL backend;
- Walter D. Potter has [a couple of papers](http://pages.citebite.com/j1m9o0t1t3vqu) on Prolog/RDBMS integration;
- Kevin Boone's paper on [Using SQL with Prolog to improve performance with large databases](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.31.6333) is also interesting;
- [and so on](http://www.google.com/search?q=Prolog+to+SQL+compiler)...

Answer (score 2):

The mapping isn't very good.  SQL, for example, doesn't do backtracking, unification, lists, or adhoc nested structures.

Prolog doesn't deal well with composite objects, indexes, etc.

I'd say it's a no-go.

Comment: I don't think you would need backtracking or unification as thing would be generated from the other end (with joins) OTOH this would kill all arbitrary depth recursion

Comment: Without backtracking, unification, recursion, and lists there isn't a whole lot left of prolog.  And you can't generate the same class of things with joins, unless you're thinking of writing self modifying SQL (queries that build queries) which I suppose is _possible_ but...

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to do an sql query from prolog, which can then be translated into prolog facts. e.g. [Prolog ODBC Library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/package/odbc.html)

This removes all restrictions and keeps the two languages separated into their proper places.

Answer (score 1):

I [wrote a translator](https://jarble.github.io/transpiler/javascript/js_transpiler/test_parser.html#%7B%22inputText%22%3A%22%5Cnis_between(A%2CB%2CC)%20%3A-%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20A%3CB%2CB%3CC.%22%2C%22inputLang%22%3A%22prolog%22%2C%22outputLang%22%3A%22mysql%22%7D) that converts a subset of Prolog into SQL user-defined functions.

This predicate in Prolog can be translated into SQL:

```
is_between(A,B,C) :- 
    A<B,B<C.
```

This is the translator's output as a MySQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_between(A double,B double,C double) RETURNS BIT BEGIN 
    RETURN A>B and B>C;
END
```

Similarly, there is a [Prolog-to-SQL compiler](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=sql_compiler) compiler for SWI-Prolog, and [another translator](https://github.com/ghxiao/nrdatalog2sql) that converts a non-recursive subset of Datalog into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

CQL, a SWI Prolog add-on pack, compiles Prolog, or rather a Prolog DSL, to SQL:

https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=cql-examples