# Comparing SQL and Prolog

Tags: sql, prolog

I've started learning Prolog and wondering about the theoretical difference from the SQL language.

For example:

- both are declarative languages
- both support a fact-driven knowledge database
- both support question-styled data-retrieving
- both support functional dependencies

Any more common points? Any notable differences?

Comment: You can use both in the same project. They mix quite well, you can use even Prolog variable unification in SQL queries with the CQL library: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=cql-examples

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Most of the (earlier) answers here are a reflection of the fact that most people do not know what SQL is (its an implementation of Relational Calculus) or what that means (that it's a form of Predicate Logic).  The following statements are true of both Prolog and SQL:

- they are both logic-driven
- they can both store, express and use relations (logical relationships in Prolog)
- they can both store and express complex logical conditions
- they both have facts(data in SQL) and can derive conclusions from those facts
- they both have queries, that do in fact mean the same thing
- they both have data(facts in Prolog) and use them similarly
- they are both programming languages
- they are both turing-complete (though it is somewhat difficult to access this in both of them)
- etc, etc..

Generally, people are not aware of these equivalences between them:

1. "Facts" and "Data" are the same thing.  This is straight out of Codd's original paper.
2. A "Relation" in Relational Theory is the same thing as a "Table" in SQL, is the same thing as a Relation or relational function in Predicate Logic and is the same thing as a tuple-set in Set Theory
3. An aliased table-expression (i.e., a View, etc.) in SQL is the same thing as a Rule in Prolog.

So what are their differences?  Although they operate across the same conceptual domains, their focuses are in completely different directions.  In Prolog terms, SQL is primarily a Fact and Relation(set) engine, whereas Prolog is primarily a Rules and Inferencing engine.  Each can do the other, to a limited extent, but it becomes increasingly difficult with even small increases in complexity.  For instance, you can do inferencing in SQL, but it is almost entirely manual in nature and not at all like the automatic forward-inferencing of Prolog.  And yes, you can store data(facts) in Prolog, but it is not at all designed for the "storage, retrieval, projection and reduction of Trillions of rows with thousands of simultaneous users" that SQL is.

Plus, SQL is primarily a Server-language paradigm, whereas Prolog is primarily a Client-language paradigm.

Comment: hmm.. while your last paragraph makes sense to me (says basically what I said) the points list does not.  As far as I can tell all of those points can be said about any (general purpose) programming language.  What makes them different and useful is their "focus".

Comment: +1. Worth a mention Datalog as the "missing link" between Prolog and Relational Calculi (and then SQL).

Comment: For a practical application of such "convertibility" see my answer to "Prolog to SQL converter" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724377/prolog-to-sql-converter/1682486#1682486) where I list some programs for such conversion.

Comment: And you have not metioned the wonders of the logical variable in prolog and all the fantastic things you can do with it.

Comment: @MaD70: How so, since I can implement Prolog in C++ (or C as I did in school), then all of these points can be said about C++ too; however for the purpose of comparing languages and when you would use one or the other of them, what their primary function is, it is not useful.  @RBarryYoung even said "Each can do the other, to a limited extent but it becomes increasingly difficult..." This is a clear indication to me that languages are fundamentally different and designed for different tasks.  Finding technical similarities is not useful and would not help OP and question.

Comment: @MaD70 (cont):  This answer is basically a mathematics hat trick.  While smart and clever it is not getting at the heart of the matter which is to explain how the two languages are different and from a design point of view.

Comment: @Hogan: no, invoking Turing-equivalence is pointless. SQL and Prolog are both declarative programming languages with a semantics based on logical inferences. Logical equivalences are established between (a relevant subset of) SQL->(Safe) Relational Calculi->Relational Algebra->Datalog->Prolog.

Comment: @Hogan: if you call "mathematics hat trick" logical equivalence of semantics we have no common base for a fruitful discussion, sorry.

Comment: @Hogan: also note what the OP wrote in his question: "I've started learning Prolog and wondering about **theoritical** [sic] difference from SQL language."

Comment: Hogan: yes, my last (full) paragraph is basically my answer to the Question, the preceding points list (and numbered points) are really a response to other statements here: that is, that these items are not useful ways to distinguish the two.  Finally, I basically agree both with your Answer and your comments, though I might differ in areas of specificity, scope and wording of our answers.

Comment: ALL: Generally I think that giving a useful answer to a question like "what's the difference between these two languages" for someone unfamiliar with both is actually very difficult and most responses tend to make the mistakes of being either 1) overly narrow and rigid in their assumptions and descriptions of languages, effectively "type-casting", or 2) impractically vague and nebulous, or 3) being overly technical in the "Formal Language Theory" sense, which is rarely of any use to someone new to a language (just try and get a good description of "Functional Languages" sometime).

Comment: @RBarryYoung: so you think that Serhiy Ryabokon, a CS student, is using the term "theoretical" in a loose sense? This is not my impression.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Excellent comments.  I will admit I tend to view things less in the theoretical and more in the applied point of view.  @MaD70 point is well taken in this case since the OP did ask for theoretical.  Mea Culpa

Comment: MaD70: well, I believe that he is probably using it in what would be commonly thought of as the *informal* sense.  I think this because it is very unusual for an actual Theoretician to use the word "theoretical" to mean what non-Theoreticians think of as the formal sense.  Theoreticians have more precise words for this like "Formal", "Grammar", "Chomsky Hierarchy", etc.  To them using "theoretical" in a question like this would be seem as hopelessly vague and would lead to questions like "Exactly which theory are you alluding to?"

Comment: mad70: Of course you may be right, the OP can set either of us straight whenever he chooses.  :-)

Comment: @RBarryYoung: of course we don't mind-reading! :-) But I have supposed that he is simply a confused student, not a theoretician. Sometimes (often?) educators doesn't state some facts explicitly when they think are obvious.

Comment: Actually, to be sure about point number 2, a table in SQL is not exactly the same as a relation in relational theory, because SQL isn't strictly relational. See CJ Date's "SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code" for some really good info in this area. I believe there's also a set of lectures on O'Reilly's website that you can pay for.

Comment: just trying to follow this thread is giving me new challenges in logic

Comment: Not claiming to be an expert, but as far as I know SQL ≈ DataLog != Prolog, because DataLog guarantees termination and is therefore not Turing-complete. So, there's a big difference between them. Datalog disallows function symbols, unlike Prolog.

Comment: @MaxB This is a widespread myth based, I believe, on the oldest SQL standards, SQL is in fact Turing-complete.  I can think of at least four different ways that the current SQL standard allows for Turing -completeness.  For instance, from the [Wikipedia article on Datalog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog#Features,_limitations_and_extensions): "*For example, the SQL:1999 standard includes recursive queries,...*"

Answer (score 54):

You are correct: Prolog and SQL are theoretically related (you asked specifically about **theoretical** differences).

I want to complement [RBarryYoung's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117651/difference-between-sql-and-prolog/2119003#2119003), giving you some hints to understand the connection, so that you have a starting point to study and understand the technicalities.

Prolog and SQL share a core: every query expressible in a subset of Prolog can be expressed in a subset of SQL and *viceversa*, i.e. these subsets are logically equivalent.

To understand how this can be true, you need to examine on what theoretical underpinnings both Prolog and SQL are based:

- **SQL**<sup>**1**</sup> is a mix of different parts, not always well integrated, [apparently from both](http://pages.citebite.com/q2i1i0y4x6tij) Relational Algebra (**RA**) and Tuple Relational Calculus (**TRC**)<sup>**2**</sup> and other parts, not related to logic (i.e. SUM, AVG operators, ORDER BY, and so on).
- **RA** is equivalent in expressive power to [**safe** (domain-independent) TRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tuple_relational_calculus&oldid=318814571#Semantic_and_syntactic_restriction_of_the_calculus) (this is known as [Codd's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_theorem)).
- **RA** is equivalent in expressive power to [safe **Datalog** without recursion and with (stratified) negation](http://books.google.com/books?id=d_Nw95OYquEC&pg=PA95&dq=%22safe+Datalog%22).
- **Datalog** can be considered a ["loose subset" of **Prolog**](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datalog&oldid=330864432#Features.2C_limitations_and_extensions)<sup>**3**</sup>; a "loose subset" in the sense that there are complications w.r.t. the operational semantics of Prolog: "*..ordering of the clauses is irrelevant in Datalog in contrast to Prolog which depends on the ordering of clauses for computing the result of the query call*" ([citing from here](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datalog&oldid=330864432#Example)).

Of course something out of these subsets needs more translation effort.

Nonetheless, I think the claim that equivalence in expressive power of the two subsets is more than an appeal to [Turing equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)<sup>**4**</sup> when considering Prolog-to-SQL translation.

**Notes:**

**1)** Unfortunately SQL can be used in contrast to RDBMS theoretical foundations (*relational algebra-calculi*); for example, [SQL tables are not necessarily relations](http://books.google.com/books?id=FU7uuHc3oNcC&pg=PA14&dq=SQL+tables+are+allowed+to+contain+duplicate+rows) - as per RA - i.e. they can be without a (primary) key, so duplicate rows are permitted. Such tables are not sets but [multisets (aka bags)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) of tuples. In such context, all theoretical results for RA, where relations are sets, are not necessarily valid.

**2)** For a translation from SQL to TRC, see [*A note on the translation of SQL to tuple calculus*](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=382398), also [here (postscript paper)](http://www.db.informatik.uni-bremen.de/publications/Gogolla_1990_EATCSBulletin.ps).

**3)** For more on the differences between Datalog and Prolog see [*What You Always Wanted to Know About Datalog (And Never Dared to Ask)*](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy562/1112_spring/instr_material/WhatYouAlwaysWantedtoKnowAboutDatalog_AndNeverDaredtoAsk.pdf#page=6) (pdf paper - links directly to page 6, heading *H. Datalog and Prolog*).

**4)** For the record: **RA** (and so their equivalents safe TRC and safe Datalog w/o recursion) is not Turing complete on purpose, to avoid never ending queries.

**Historical note:** Prolog and Codd's Relational Algebra were conceived around the same time (end of '60s early '70s) in different contexts - Colmerauer conceived Prolog for natural language processing and Codd conceived RA as a theoretical foundation of Relational DBMS. So, any theoretical connection between Prolog-Datalog-RA-SQL was necessarily established *a posteriori* and is implicit in the fact that they are all based on *first-order predicate calculus* (aka [*first order logic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic)).

Comment: +1 Excellent overview of some of the theoretical issues at hand.

Comment: The “What You Always Wanted to Know About Datalog (And Never Dared to Ask)” link is broken. The one that works:  https://personal.utdallas.edu/~gupta/courses/acl/papers/datalog-paper.pdf

Comment: Artem’s updated link is now also broken, here’s one that works: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3296132_What_you_Always_Wanted_to_Know_About_Datalog_And_Never_Dared_to_Ask

Answer (score 27):

Prolog and SQL are both based on first order logic, but SQL tables are simple binary relations, whereas Prolog predicates are Horn clauses.

This is not some obscure theoretical point. SQL binary relations are statements of fact, of the form:

*f(A, B, C ... N)*

Where *f* is the name of the relation and *A...N* its variables. Prolog binary relations are implications, of the form:

*A <- B, C, D ... N*

Where A ... N are themselves Horn clauses. SQL relations are an efficient way to describe data. Prolog relations describe complex relationships between data, themselves stored as data.

It is important to understand that in Prolog, there is no separation between data and operation. Prolog facts, rules and queries are all Horn clauses, therefore data, something that gets lost in translation in most university courses. Prolog is not like C but with facts instead of variables and rules instead of functions. On the other hand, SQL is a lot like Prolog without the rules or queries.

SQL queries are also logic predicates, but SQL queries are not stored in the database itself. Rather, they are used to extract data sets from the database of facts. You could store a query as a table row in a SQL database but you couldn't execute it in that form.

Prolog queries are stored in the database like any other Prolog predicate, because they are like any other Prolog predicate. Queries are Horn clauses of the form:

*<- B, C, D ... N*

So implications with a precedent but no antecedent, therefore always false. Facts are Horn clauses with an antecedent but no precedent, of the form:

*A <-*

So always true. Prolog proves a query by refutation: if it can't find a fact (or rule) that proves it, it will state the goal is true, since a query is always false. In the process, some variables are bound so result sets can be constructed, much like SQL does with SELECT queries.

Modern SQL DBMSs have features like stored procedures and flow control language so SQL can be used for inference (not that you *want* to do inference in SQL). Prolog comes ready with an inference engine tuned to its database of Horn clauses, because that's an efficient way to do inference over databases of facts stated as binary relations (and no, not just because it's pretty).

Prolog's homoiconic nature (data is operation is data) means that new new data has to be added to the database, therefore to the program, because the database is the program. So everytime a new fact is added to its database (typically using assert/1) the whole program must be decompiled. This is a huge PITA and makes Prolog inefficient for storing large data sets, though there is no reason why it has to be inefficient at data *retrieval* and Prolog systems will use the same algorithms as SQL systems for that purpose. SQL on the other hand is well suited for both storage and retrieval.

Finally, Prolog has a few features that SQL just doesn't have, namely its super-pattern-matching called unification, negation as failure and syntactic elements that facilitate list processing and grammar declaration (Definite Clause Grammar notation). Those are just a happy accident and were mostly added to the language because they were en vogue in the time it was first created (thanks to LISP). SQL got recursive queries relatively recently so Prolog can't boast that anymore.

And of course both languages are weak at I/O and maths, although at least you can do some arithmetic in Prolog without having to pull your hair out *all* the way.

So, really, Prolog and SQL are as much alike as C and Haskell. They're both based on the same root abstraction, first order logic (like C and Haskell are both based on algebra) but things get very different pretty quickly after that. Also, from the point of view of language design, SQL tends to be fractured, with many different language features (pedicates, queries, data manipulation language....). Prolog's design is extremely consistent, so that the whole language is really just predicates and a few punctuation marks.

For me, the most important difference is this: I don't like SQL but I have to work with it. I love Prolog, but I can't use it at work. Life is unfair :)

Comment: Damn nice explanation!! :)

Comment: How is `f(A, B, C ... N)` *binary* and not *N-ary*?

Comment: The list of arguments of f/n is a tuple. You can think of the arguments as a nested tree: (A(B(C...)N)). So in f(A, B,C,... N) the first argument is related to the tuple of subsequent arguments by the relation f. So f is a relation between two things, even when there's more than one thing in the second thing :)

Answer (score 7):

There are many differences which I think become clear when you start using them.  Remember because of changes in terminology, somethings which are called the same thing in the past mean very different things now.

Very broad overview of difference.

SQL statements work against a relational database and query (ask for) data from that database, changes to that data and the results are exactly expressed in the language, whereas in Prolog you define facts and a logic engine generates new facts based off of the existing facts.  New data (facts) are created via evaluation.

They both use something called queries (but they work totally differently) and they both have data (but use it differently.)

The use cases for SQL and Prolog are also totally different.  It would never make sense to store an address list in Prolog whereas that is exactly what SQL was designed to do.

Simply put SQL is used to access a data store and Prolog is an expression evaluator.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference in my eyes is that SQL retrieves rows from tables - that is, from a finite set of instantiated objects corresponding to certaing filter conditions. On the other hand, Prolog gives you theoretically all the instantiable objects that satisfy the conditions. And while in Prolog you can also retrieve entities from a finite set, in SQL you can't fetch all the values from a theoretically infinite set.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main difference is that Prolog is a query language used for matching complicated patterns against a database of simple facts. SQL on the other hand is limited to relational databases.

Comment: Are you saying SQL is more limited than Prolog -- I'm not sure that comparison even makes sense.

Comment: No, I wasn't making a comparison, I was saying that SQL is only used to query relational logic.

Answer (score -3):

Just a few thoughts:

1. SQL is a query language for (maybe arbitrary complex) accessing to (relational) data, it's not a programming language.
2. Even if treat SQL as programming language - it's not Turing complete. I can hardly imagine sql query returning sum of 1 to 100 (for example).
3. SQL is language for accessing/manipulating (DML) to *data* bases, where Prolog is a language for working with *knowledge* bases (& rule resolution engine, of cause). Virtually Prolog is no more then simply **unification** & **backtracking**.
4. This is not saying about the application domains of SQL & Prolog, which are of cause totally different - efficient (regular) data storage & AI/symbolic computations/parsing/expert systems/constraint solvers/.../much more.

Comment: SQL *is* a programming language, its just not a GP (general-purpose) programming language.  As of ANSI SQL 9x, it *is* turing-complete, though that's largely irrelevant.

Comment: FYI, this is perfectly correct SQL: SELECT SUM(value) FROM Integers WHERE Value BETWEEN 1 AND 100

Comment: Well, I had in mind a case when you are not using any table (additional data). Like follows in prolog:

    sum1(From, From, S, S) :-!.
    sum1(From, To, S0, S) :-
     S1 is S0 + From,
     From1 is From + 1,
     sum1(From1, To, S1, S).

    ?- sum1(1, 101, 0, R).
    R = 5050.

I bet this not possible with an SQL. Otherwise consider the case of finding N's Fibonacci number. Will a table help you? 
Btw, please provide an url, stating that ANSI SQL is Turing complete. I used to know that relational calculus is not Turing complete by design, though some implementations can be..

Comment: Tables are inherent to a table-based paradigm like SQL.  And yes, I can do your Peano's inferencing trick in SQL, but the point is that you do NOT have to.  And you would also be wrong about the Fibonacci series in SQL.  Just at the crudest level: ANSI/ISO SQL has had recursion since ISO 9x which means that it is fully Turing-Complete (because recursion and iteration are the same in programming theory), which means it can compute anything that any other language can compute.  And SQL is a superset of Relational Calculus, so you can not make that logical leap.

Comment: Are you saying of stored procedures/functions?
If yes, then I agree on that, but to me this is another case.
Cause, comparing Prolog to stored procedure language (be it pgplsql/sql server dialect/whatever) is not far from comparing Prolog, say, to PHP or Java. Because, technically, stored procedures are not essential to SQL, it's just a metter of optimization (moving application logic closer to data).

Comment: @Xonix: no, he is speaking about recursive extension to SQL properly, specifically SELECT statement's WITH clause. See, for example: *Understanding the WITH Clause*, by Jonathan Gennick (http://www.gennick.com/with.html).

Answer (score -3):

xonix, you need more development experience to say whether something can be done in sql or not.

Below are at least 2 solutions for your fibo series. One using `Stored Procedure` and the other using `CTE`.  Take your pick.

**METHOD 1**

```
declare @a int, @b int, @c int, @i int, @N int = 10
select @a=0, @b=1, @i=0, @c=0
print @a
print @b
while @i < @N 
Begin
set @c=@a+@b
print @c
set @i=@i+1
set @a=@b
set @b=@c
end
```

**METHOD 2**

```
WITH FibonacciNumbers (RecursionLevel, FibonacciNumber, NextNumber) 
AS (
-- Anchor member definition
SELECT  
0  AS RecursionLevel,
0  AS FibonacciNumber,
1  AS NextNumber
UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
SELECT  a.RecursionLevel + 1             AS RecursionLevel,
a.NextNumber                     AS FibonacciNumber,
a.FibonacciNumber + a.NextNumber AS NextNumber
FROM FibonacciNumbers a
WHERE a.RecursionLevel < 10
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT 
'F' + CAST( fn.RecursionLevel AS VARCHAR) AS FibonacciOrdinal, 
fn.FibonacciNumber,
fn.NextNumber
FROM FibonacciNumbers fn; 
GO
```