# Rules engine for spatial and temporal reasoning?

Tags: spatial, drools, rule-engine, temporal, jess

I have an application that receives a number of datums that characterize 3 dimensional spatial and temporal processes.  It then filters these datums and creates actions which are then sent to processes that perform the actions.  Rinse and repeat.

At present, I have a collection of custom filters that perform a lot of complicated spatial/temporal calculations.

Many times as I discuss my system to individuals in my company, they ask if I'm using a rules engine.

I have yet to find a rules engine that is able to reason well temporally and spatially.  (Things like: When are two 3D entities ever close?  Is 3D entity A ever contained in 3D region B?  If entity C is near entity D but oriented backwards relative to C then perform action D.)

I have looked at Drools, Cyc, Jess in the past (say 3-4 years ago).  It's time to re-examine the state of the art.  Any suggestions?  Any standards that you know of that support this kind of reasoning?  Any defacto standards?  Any applications?

Thanks!

Comment: Tweaked so that it makes it clear that I'm interested in 3D entities, not 2D entities.  Most of the suggestions so far have focused on the 2D problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premise - remember that a SQL-based<sup>1</sup> DBMS is a (quite capable) inference engine, as can be seen from these comparisons between SQL and Prolog:

- [prolog to SQL converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724377/prolog-to-sql-converter/1682486#1682486)
- [difference between SQL and Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117651/difference-between-sql-and-prolog/2124585#2124585)

To address specifically your spatio-temporal applications, this book will help:

- [TEMPORAL DATA AND THE RELATIONAL MODEL](http://books.google.com/books?id=grTubz0fjSEC) - A Detailed Investigation into
  the Application of **Interval and Relation Theory** to the Problem of Temporal Database Management.

That is, combining Interval and Relation Theory is possible to reasoning about spatio-temporal problems effectively (see [5.2 Applications of Intervals](http://books.google.com/books?id=grTubz0fjSEC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q=a%20rectangular%20plot%20of%20ground)).

Of course, if your SQL-based DBMS is not (yet) equipped with interval (and other) operators you will need to extend it appropriately (*via* store-procedures and/or User-Defined Functions - UDFs).

**Update:** skimming the paper pointed out [in comments by timemirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469567/rules-engine-for-spatial-and-temporal-reasoning/2481625#2481625) ([Towards a 3D Spatial Query Language for Building Information Models](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.71.9354)) they do essentially what I touched on above:

> *(last page)*
>
> IMPLEMENTATION CONCEPTS
>
> The implementation of the abstract
>   type system into a query language will
>   be performed on the basis of the query
>   language SQL, which is a widely
>   established standard in the field of
>   object-relational databases. The
>   international standard SQL:1999
>   extends the relational model to
>   include object-oriented aspects, such
>   as the possibility to define complex
>   abstract data types with integrated
>   methods.

I do not concur with the "object-relational database" terminology (for reason off-topic here) but I think the rest is pertinent.

**Update:** a quote regardind 3D and interval theory from the book cited above:

> NOTE: All of the intervals discussed
>   so far can be thought of as
>   one-dimensional. However, we might
>   want to combine two one-dimensional
>   intervals to form a twodimensional
>   interval. For example, a rectangular
>   plot of ground might be thought of as
>   a two-dimensional interval, because it
>   is, by definition, an object with
>   length and width, each of which is
>   basically a one-dimensional interval
>   measured along some axis. And, of
>   course, **we can extend this idea to any
>   number of dimensions**. For example, a
>   (rather simple!) building might be
>   regarded as a three-dimensional
>   interval: It is an object with length,
>   width, and height, or in other words a
>   cuboid. (More realistically, a
>   building might be regarded as a set of
>   several such cuboids that overlap in
>   various ways.) And so on. In what
>   follows, however, we will restrict our
>   attention to one-dimensional intervals
>   specifically, barring explicit
>   statements to the contrary, and we
>   will omit the "one-dimensional"
>   qualifier for simplicity.

**Note**

1. I wrote *SQL-based* and not *relational* because there are ways to use such DBMSes that completely deviate from relational theory.

Answer (score 1):

This is Spatial Reasoning... a few models but 9DE-IM is now accepted by OGC and implemented in PostGIS and other programming tools.

PostGIS implements a spatial reasoning engine based on dimensionally extended 9 intersection model... 9DE-IM..

http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ch04.html#DE-9IM 
check sect 4.3.6.1. Theory...

---

So does the Java Topology Suite (and Net Topology suite for C# etc)...

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTDOC/Point+Set+Theory+and+the+DE-9IM+Matrix

In particualr check out the geometry.relate stuff.. such as

boolean isRelated = geometry.relate( geometry2, "T*T***T**" )

You can test the relationships, or filter data based on them.
Works with pts, lines, polygons etc...

---

This might help on temporal stuff..

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.87.4643&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Another link which may be of interest....   http://www.allegrograph.net/agraph/support/documentation/current/temporal-tutorial.html

Comment: A 3D example of DE-9IM approach for buildings 
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.71.9354&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 1):

Check out SpatialRules at http://www.objectfx.com/. It's a geospatial complex event processor for 2D and 3D.