# temporal rule engine for alarm management

Tags: python, alarm, rule-engine, clips, temporal

I am looking for a rule based system (forward chaining) like [CLIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLIPS)  than can do temporal reasoning, i.e. phrases of the form:

If condition active for more than 10s...
If condition1 becomes active less than 10s after condition2 becomes active...
If more than n events during 10s...
If first condition1 then condition2 and then condition3 not more than 2 s apart...

This is for an alarm system, I would prefer a c or python library or something that can be easily interfaced to python.

I've found this discussion, but it did not help much:
[Rules engine for spatial and temporal reasoning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469567/rules-engine-for-spatial-and-temporal-reasoning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not been modified for several years, but there is a Python library for CLIPS on sourceforge called [PyCLIPS](http://pyclips.sourceforge.net/web/).  They have a rather complete [manual](http://pyclips.sourceforge.net/manual/) too.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do temporal reasoning with CLIPS?

Comment: It looks possible.  There's a course at a college in France that has students do it as [an exercise](http://www-prima.imag.fr/jlc/Courses/2011/ENSI2.SIRR/ENSI2.SIRR.EX3-Allen-EN.pdf).

Comment: Ok, then the answer will be left as an exercise for the reader. Thanks