# Spatial Events in Drools Fusion & WSO2 Complex Event Processor/Siddhi

Tags: geospatial, drools-fusion, siddhi, wso2-cep

I’ve been looking into the **Drools Fusion** Complex Event Processing component and the **WSO2 Complex Event Processor**/**Siddhi**  and I was wondering if one/both of these components are capable to handle **spatial** events for  2D and 3D events.

I’m interested in creating triggers such as:

- If the distance between 2 points is less than [X] miles
- If a object is inside an area/polygon
- If a object is outside an area/polygon

Are these triggers such as these possible to create or do I need to write extensions/ custom functions?

If spatial event are possible, where can I find some documentation that I can look into.

**What I’ve found so far:**

Drools Fusion:
http://blog.athico.com/2009/10/secret-sauce.html | Indicating that spatial based questions should be possible (It’s an old source however).

[Rules engine for spatial and temporal reasoning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469567/rules-engine-for-spatial-and-temporal-reasoning) | Similar question but it’s very old

WSO2 Complex Event Processor/Siddhi:
[link]: wso2.com/about/news/wso2-vp-of-platform-evangelism-to-lead-workshop-on-improving-team-performance-with-big-data-streamin/ & [link]: prweb.com/releases/2014_WSO2/03_StructureData/prweb11661730.htm | “spatial and temporal processing” are talked about.

[link]: mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/architecture/2013-October/013646.html | Questions about Spatial Extensions

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP310/Writing+Extentions+to+Siddhi | Siddhi Extensions

(Sorry for the [Link]: part, i can't seem to post more than 2 links since I'm new here.)

Thank you for your time and effort!

Best regards,

Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't be able to answer regarding support in Drools Fusion since am not much aware of Drools. Regarding WSO2 CEP, you can find some articles in [1,2]. More functionalities are being added to Siddhi as extensions by using external libraries as discussed in the architecture@wso2.org mail thread pointed out by you in the question.

Also there is some work for a geo dashboard done in [3]. There are no publicly available articles/ tutorials as yet on these, but you can drop a mail to dev@wso2.org to get more info on the implementation details, capabilities, if you are interested.. :-)

[1] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/09/fleet-management-with-wso2-cep/

[2] http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2014/07/tutorial-on-running-cep-fleet-management-samples/

[3] https://github.com/tmkasun/geo_dashboard

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your input :)

I can't mark the question as answered yet since i don't have information about Drools Fusion yet. But writing extensions to WSO2/Siddhi would be a viable option.